# githubでコードを完全一致で検索する

Tags: github

githubでコードを完全一致検索したいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?

github.comのあるリポジトリの中で、helloという関数の定義を見たい時に`def hello():`と検索してもdefとhelloが出てきてしまいます。二重引用符をつけてもうまくいきません
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: 参考:[How to search on github to get exact matches (like what quotes do for Google)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33237640)

Answer (score 3):

私の場合は以下の方法でよく探しています。

1. その関数又はクラスがファイルを代表する名前だと信じ、`Find file` で探す。
2. Google 検索の [`site:` コマンド](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?visit_id=1-636529989990305028-1699318514&p=adv_operators&hl=ja&rd=1) (e.g. `site:github.com/～～～`) を検索キーワードと併用して検索。

特に 2. は強力ですね（笑

Answer (score 0):

githubの検索でどうでしょうか。
一つ目が`"int main"`で完全一致、二つ目が`int main`で`int`と`main`を両方検索になります。

["int main"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22int+main%22&type=Code)

[int main](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?o=asc&q=int+main&s=indexed&type=Code)